# Javascript Creating Arrays with Unique Names with a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got a real doosy on my hands, a real doosy indeed.

I'm trying to make an array with values that are arrays with unique names.
The problem is that I just overwrite the same Eventarrayarray!

> var Eventarray = new Array(); var Eventarrayarray = new Array();
>
> for (var f = 0; f < data.events.event.length; f++) {
>
> ```
> if(data.events.event[f].hasOwnProperty('title')) {
>
>   Eventarrayarray["marker"] = marker[f];
>   Eventarrayarray["content"] = content[f];
>   Eventarrayarray["title"] = data.events.event[f].title;
>   Eventarrayarray["description"] = data.events.event[f].description;
>   Eventarrayarray["start_time"] = data.events.event[f].start_time;
>   Eventarrayarray["venue"] = data.events.event[f].venue_name;
>   Eventarrayarray["city"] = data.events.event[f].city;
>   Eventarrayarray["state"] = data.events.event[f].state;
>
>   Eventarray[f] = Eventarrayarray;
> }
> ```
>
> }
>
> console.log(Eventarray);

WHAT GIVES?!!

Comment: What you are trying to do is create a map. A javascript object is a map. So instead of creating an Array, do `events = {}` and assign key value pairs like `events.name = value` or `events['name'] = value`.

Comment: yeah, but what about when I get to the second event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't heard of a doosy yet, but I think you'll need to instantiate a separate `Eventarrayarray` Array instance for each iteration:

```
for (var f = 0; f < data.events.event.length; f++) {
  if (data.events.event[f].hasOwnProperty('title')) {
    var Eventarrayarray = new Array();

    Eventarrayarray["marker"] = marker[f];
    ...

    Eventarray[f] = Eventarrayarray;
}
```

Edit: Although this change should address your initial concern, it remains a non-standard way of assigning element values to an array (read: An `Array` doesn't work like that). It would appear that you intended to use an object instead:

```
for (var f = 0; f < data.events.event.length; f++) {
  if (data.events.event[f].hasOwnProperty('title')) {
    Eventarray[f] = {
      marker: marker[f],
      ...
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment:

The *Eventeventarray* should be an object (arrays are just objects with a special length property, you are using an array like an object and not using any of its array specialness), here's what I think you're trying to create:

```
eventArray = [
  {
    marker: marker[f],
    content: content[f],
    title: data.events.event[f].title,
    description: data.events.event[f].description,
    start_time: data.events.event[f].start_time,
    venue: data.events.event[f].venue_name,
    city: data.events.event[f].city,
    state: data.events.event[f].state
  }
];
```

Also, variable names starting with a capital letter are, by convention, reserved for constructors. Try to keep names descriptive of the content, not the structure, so *events* might be an array of individual *event* objects:

```
var events = [event, event, ...];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll do these things from now on